# Run some piece of code only when crossing some point

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to update some data whenever scrollbar crosses some point, it looks like this: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/93gz3u1L/14/)

```
var scrollElement = document.getElementById('scrollElement');
var line = document.getElementById('line');


scrollElement.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
    this.scrollLeft += e.deltaY;
    if (this.scrollLeft > 106) {
    console.log('something')
  } else if (this.scrollLeft < 106) {
    console.log('something else')
  }
});
```

The problem in the above code is that IFs are executed everytime the scrollbar is below 106px or above 106px. I want to execute some of them ONLY when crossing the line. So basically I want to do something only when crossing from Left to Right and I want to do something only when crossing from Right to Left. How to achieve such result? Thanks in advance!

Comment: so add a booelan after it has run

Comment: can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

So add a boolean

```
var hasRun = false;
```

and add it to the check

```
if(this.scrollLeft < 10 && !hasRun) { hasRun = true; }
```